# Finite, simple group with $p+1$ Sylow $p$-subgroups has order dividing $p(p^2-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I'm reviewing for my final, and the following is a (non-homework) question that I'm stuck on:

> Let $G$ be a finite and simple group, and suppose $|\mathrm{Syl}_p(G)| = p+1$.
>
> (a) Prove that $G$ can be embedded into $S_{p+1}$
>
> (b) Prove that $p^2 \nmid |G|$
>
> (c) Prove that $C_G(P) = P$
>
> (d) Prove that $|G|$ divides $p(p^2 - 1)$

I used (a) to prove (b), and (b) implies that $P\in \mathrm{Syl}_p(G)$ has order $p$.  I used that to prove (c), but I'm not seeing how any of this implies (d).  Any hints to show (d)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider that we are given that $|G: N_G(P)| = p+1$ and we have shown in part (c) that $|C_G(P)| = p$.  What can we say about $|N_G(P): C_G(P)|$?

Comment: So $[N_G(P) : C_G(P)] = [N_G(P):P]$, and $[G:P] = [G:N_G(P)][N_G(P):C_G(P)]$, so $|G| = p(p+1)[N_G(P):C_G(P)]$.  I need to show then that $[N_G(P):C_G(P)]$ divides $p-1$.

Comment: @MöbiusDickus that's what you need to do